# x times recursive loop with multiple ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, recursion, active-directory

I have been using the [Recursive DirectReport](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/10/powershell-who-reports-to-whom-active.html) code, with a view of amending it to only look X levels of direct reports down (e.g. CEO plus 2 levels down).

I'm using an additional `$count` variable and settled on using an `if ($count -ge 0) {<code>}` and `$count--` to control the recursion, however I've been up and down the code, in and out of each For loop, trying to find the right place; with mixed and sometimes hilarious results.

When I stared, I was pretty sure putting the `if` statement around `Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName $_` was going to be a 2 minute job.  I'm about 6+ hours in to making it work. Anyone up for the challenge?

```
function Get-ADdirectReports {
    Param($SamAccountName, $count)

    Get-Aduser -Identity $SamAccountName -Properties directreports -Server contoso.net:3268 | ForEach-Object {     
        ($_.directreports) | ForEach-Object {
            # Output the current Object information
            Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties manager -Server contoso.net:3268 |
                Select-Object -Property Name, SamAccountName, @{L="Manager";E={
                    (Get-Aduser -Identity $_.Manager -Server contoso.net:3268).SamAccountName
                }}
            # Find the DirectReports of the current item
            Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName $_
        }
    }
}

Get-ADdirectReports TheCEO 5
```

Comment: `Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName $_` -> `if ($count -gt 0) {Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName $_ ($count-1)}`?

Comment: That's what I thought, and alluded to in my third paragraph.  Regardless of the $count value, it only returns a single level below the level entered in the `$SamAccountName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gives the desired results:

```
function Get-ADdirectReports
{
PARAM ($SamAccountName, $count)

    Get-Aduser -identity $SamAccountName -Properties directreports -server contoso.net:3268 | ForEach-Object {
        $tick++
        ($_.directreports) | foreach-object {
           # Output the current Object information, uses ad-object just in case a contact is used
            Get-ADobject -identity $_ -Properties manager,SamAccountName -server contoso.net:3268 | Select-Object -Property Name, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, @{ L = "Manager"; E = { (Get-Aduser -identity $_.manager -server contoso.net:3268).samaccountname }}, @{ L = "Level"; E = {$tick} }
            if ($tick -le $count) {
                # Find the DirectReports of the current item
                Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName $_
            }
        }
    }
}
Get-ADdirectReports carters 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't answer much, but this one was interesting

The "# Find the DirectReports of the current item" only has the samaccountname and not the count; hence count defaults to 0 :)

Try:

```
 # Find the DirectReports of the current item 
Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName $_ $count
```